# How to mock streams that are created using supplier and used twice?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have class `RetrieveOrderService`, in which `Execute` method takes two input parameters and uses a supplier to use the stream twice. However, when `supplier.get()` is called the second time, it throws an error "stream has already been operated or closed" and I do not know why.

```
 class DataService{
    public void getStream(){
           Map<Order, String> orders = new HashMap<Order, String> 
               ();
           orders.put(new Order("1", "OPEN"), "t1");
           orders.put(new Order("2", "CLOSE"), "t2");
           return orders.keySet().stream();
     }
  }

  class RetrieveOrderService {
         @Inject DataService dataService;

         public Map<String, Long> execute(String id, String type){
                Supplier<Stream<Order>> supplier = dataService.getStream(): // This returns a stream
                 if(supplier.get().collect(Collectors.toList()).size == 0) {
                          return Collections.emptyMap();
                 }

                 Stream<Order> orders = supplier.get().filter(ordr -> order.getType().contains(type));
                          // my test fails here with error stream has already been operated or closed
         }
    }

   class RetrieveOrderServiceTest {
      @Mock DataService dataService;
      @InjectMocks RetrieveOrderService service;

      @Before 
      public void init(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            Supplier<Stream<Order>> supplier = service.getStream();
            when(service.getStream()).thenReturn(supplier);
      }

      @Test
      public void test(){
           assertEquals(expected, service.execute("1", "OPEN"); // the test fails when supplier.get() is called second time in RetrieveOrderService.
      }
   }
```

Comment: You need to at least include the complete details in terms of what happens to the Stream that you've created. Also, looks like a similar question was asked previously as well.

Comment: I think my code has lot of details and i have explained what happens when i am trying to call execute method.

Comment: Just remove that first `if` statement. It wastes significantly more CPU cycles than the early return will ever gain. It’s one of the worst imaginable ways to test for an empty stream, but even if you replace it by a reasonable test, it would need the same amount of CPU cycles than performing the actual operation on an empty stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it twice, create and return a new stream by adding another `thenReturn`

```
when(service.getStream()).thenReturn(service.getStream())
    .thenReturn(service.getStream()); //(Presumably) Returns a fresh stream
```

You didn't add details on how the stream is generated behind `service.getStream()`. To make it work, each call to `getStream` must return a new stream created out of something.

**UPDATE**

> *I have provided implementation for getStream()*

You are creating a fresh new stream each time. So, the above should work

Sidenote: You need not complicate things here by returning a stream. I do not know if there is any reason for doing so. Returning just the Map would be simpler (for your testing and for the readers). Thus, I agree with @Ravindra Ranwala's point.

Comment: I have provided implementation for getStream()

Comment: You are creating a fresh new stream each time. So, the above should work

Comment: @user7 I wouldn’t say that it should work, as the OP’s code doesn’t even compile. It’s trying to return a `Stream` from a `void` method and tries to assign the result of that method to a `Supplier`, two fundamental errors her. Even if we assume that the method’s return type is supposed to be `Stream` so its `return` statement would work, the code is still missing how it will get from the `Stream` returning method to an actual `Supplier`, if not with a plain, invalid assignment. But that’s the crucial part that will determine whether the supplier truly return a new stream each time.

Comment: @Holger Yes. The OP's code is partial/incomplete. I only considered the last return statement to arrive at this